# How to replace text with lorem ipsum text

Tags: javascript, text, lorem-ipsum

I have a text that I want to replace with lorem ipsum.

What I mean by that is that I want to be able to provide my text as an input and to get back the exact text length, case match, punctuation marks as an ouptut in a form or lorem ipsum.

For example

`I, have a text that I want to replace. END;`

might became

`D, quam e leme ntum F erme po tincidu. PUR;`

I've googled for that [library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lorem-ipsum) but haven't yet figure out how to adopt that for my use case.

I wonder if you have any ideas how to achieve my goal. What I am trying to achieve is to tun the original text into unreadable text, keeping the formatting, so no one else can guess the original text. So I thought that lorem ipsum might be the way to go.

I was thinking to take each paragraph and based on that paragraph to generate an input for lorem ipsurm library, but seems there is no control over the uppercase/lowercase.

Comment: Where did you get stuck, exactly? Is there a reason you have to use that specific library (or any library at all)?

Comment: What I am trying to achieve is to tun the original text into unreadable text, keeping the text formatting and punctuation marks, so no one else can guess the original text. So I thought that lorem ipsum might be the way to go.

Comment: Is the transformation supposed to be reversible?  If it isn't, what prevents you from simply substituting ordinary Lipsum, ignoring the position of the punctuation?  Why would the position of the punctuation need to be preserved?

Comment: While I appreciate the information what you provided doesn't answer the questions that I asked. What code have you written to accomplish this, what problems are you having with that code, what errors (if any) are reported? And: you linked to a specific library, is it a requirement to use that specific library (or any other)?

Comment: @RobertHarvey The transformation should not be reversible. All I want is to keep the text size, formatting and punctuation to have the shape of the original text.

Comment: Well, the example you gave seems to follow a simple pattern of vowel+consonant substitution (it's not Lipsum).  Why don't you try writing some code?

Comment: @DavidThomas I was thinking to take each paragraph and based on that paragraph to generate an input for lorem ipsurm library, but seems there is no control over the uppercase/lowercase.

Comment: So this seems like you might have to try writing something yourself to achieve your desired result; this is probably easier than you might think once you identify the various steps you'd need to take to implement a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one approach to generate jibberish to match the shape of `inputText`.

```js
const jibberRaw = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum';
const jibberLetters = jibberRaw.toLowerCase().replaceAll(/[^a-z]/g, '');
function jibberOfShape(shape) {
    return Array.from(shape).map((char, index) => {
      const charIsLetter = char.match(/[a-zA-Z]/);
      if (charIsLetter) {
        const wasUpper = char === char.toUpperCase();
        const jibberLetter = jibberLetters[index % jibberLetters.length];
        return wasUpper
          ? jibberLetter.toUpperCase()
          : jibberLetter;
      } else {
        return char;
      }
    }).join('');
}

const inputText = 'I, have a text that I want to replace. END;';
console.log(inputText);
console.log(jibberOfShape(inputText));
```